# Google Drive v3 API file - 403 when specifying alt=media

Tags: c#, rest, google-drive-api

This C# code, with a proper access token (for scope drive.readonly) in the Authorization header, will work fine and return the file metadata in json format

```
_httpClient.GetAsync($"https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{someDriveFileId}")
```

However this code (still with the same access token) will return a 403 :

```
_httpClient.GetAsync($"https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{someDriveFileId}?alt=media")
```

And the following response html (exactly as returned) :

```
<html><title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title><a
href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo
aria-label=Google></span></a><p><b>403 Forbidden</b><p>Your client
does not have permission.\n
```

I've been using this code in production for years and it worked fine, so i suppose it's related to the recent changes at Google regarding the OAuth screens ? 
I'm not sure what i should change here, or what i'm doing (now) wrong. Also the message seems a little sketchy for something made at Google, makes me think there is maybe an issue on their side ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @Iamblichus for fixing the layout of my original answer. I'm newer to stackoverflow posting.

Even though the change in the original answer appears to be at the root of the problem, I found it difficult to use the troubleshooting steps to come to a working solution. I also was already passing the Authorization Bearer token solution, and that was not fixing my problem. After some trial and error the change I had to make was:

Broken GET URL:

https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/MY_FILE_ID?key=MY_KEY&alt=media&source=downloadUrl

Working GET URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/MY_FILE_ID?alt=media&source=downloadUrl

**NOTE:**

- I am using [v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get) of the API, so you would need to update to url to [v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) if using that.
- In the file object I get from the google filepicker v2 API, I don't get back a single URL that supports the change made in authentication. I had to concat the file.selfLink string to make the new URL work

```js
var url = file.selfLink + "?alt=media&source=downloadUrl";
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Is it possible that https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api is your problem?:

> download calls to files.get, revisions.get and files.export endpoints which authenticate using the access token in the query parameter **will no longer be supported**.

Only requests that download media content (`alt=media`) are affected by this change.

The access token should be provided in the HTTP header, like `Authorization: Bearer oauth2-token` or, if that's not possible, follow the workarounds provided in the referenced documentation:

> For file downloads, redirect to the webContentLink which will instruct the browser to download the content. If the application wants to display the file to the user, they can simply redirect to the alternateLink in v2 or webViewLink in v3.
>
> For file exports, redirect to the export link in exportLinks with the desired mime type which will instruct the browser to download the content.

#### Reference:

- [Changes in authorization to Google Drive API](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api)
- [Authorization via HTTP header](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/query-parameters)
- [v2 files get documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get)
- [v3 files get documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

Comment: Please add the mentioned quotes/steps directly in your answer. And the link just for further reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i had hope, but i already provide an OAuth 2 token in the Authorization header.

Comment: @JérômeS. I have the same issue. I'm sending the token, but get the same response you get :(

Comment: As a side note, this is only affecting us when using non GSUITE documents. This makes it so that only https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive is broken and not https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_google_document

Comment: @JérômeS I just updated the answer with how I got mine to start working.